# How do you create a "virtual" page in WordPress

Tags: url-rewriting, api, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to create a custom API endpoint in WordPress, and I need to redirect requests to a virtual page in the root of WordPress to an actual page that ships with my plug-in.  So basically, all requests to the one page are actually routed to the other.

Example:
`http://mysite.com/my-api.php` => `http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-api.php`

The point of this is to make the url for the API endpoint as short as possible (similar to `http://mysite.com/xmlrpc.php` but to ship the actual API endpoint file with the plug-in rather than requiring the user to move files around in their installation and/or hack core.

My first stab was to add a custom rewrite rule.  However, this had two problems.

1. The endpoint always had a trailing slash.  It became `http://mysite.com/my-api.php/`
2. My rewrite rule was only ever partially applied.  It wouldn't redirect to `wp-content/plugins...`, it would redirect to `index.php&wp-content/plugins...`.  This lead to WordPress displaying either a page not found error or just defaulting to the homepage.

Ideas?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There are two types of rewrite rules in WordPress: internal rules (stored in the database and parsed by [WP::parse_request()](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-includes/classes.php#L121)), and external rules (stored in `.htaccess` and parsed by Apache). You can choose either way, depending on how much of WordPress you need in your called file.

**External Rules:**

The external rule is the easiest to set up and to follow. It will execute `my-api.php` in your plugin directory, without loading anything from WordPress.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse9870_init_external' );
function wpse9870_init_external()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $plugin_url = plugins_url( 'my-api.php', __FILE__ );
    $plugin_url = substr( $plugin_url, strlen( home_url() ) + 1 );
    // The pattern is prefixed with '^'
    // The substitution is prefixed with the "home root", at least a '/'
    // This is equivalent to appending it to `non_wp_rules`
    $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'my-api.php$', $plugin_url );
}
```

**Internal Rules:**

The internal rule requires some more work: first we add a rewrite rule that adds a query vars, then we make this query var public, and then we need to check for the existence of this query var to pass the control to our plugin file. By the time we do this, the usual WordPress initialization will have happened (we break away right before the regular post query).

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse9870_init_internal' );
function wpse9870_init_internal()
{
    add_rewrite_rule( 'my-api.php$', 'index.php?wpse9870_api=1', 'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse9870_query_vars' );
function wpse9870_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'wpse9870_api';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse9870_parse_request' );
function wpse9870_parse_request( &$wp )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'wpse9870_api', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        include 'my-api.php';
        exit();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I just want to add that its important to go to the Permalinks page and click "Save Changes" in the WP-Admin. I was playing with this for an hour before thinking that I needed to refresh the permalinks... Unless someone knows a function that can do that?

Comment: For the external rule: Because the path to my web root had a whitespace character, this caused apache to fall over. Whitespaces need to be escaped if they exist in the path to your wordpress installation.

Comment: Works, but I can't seem to access any passed query variables with `get_query_vars()` in my-api.php. I checked what variables are loaded. And the only var that is set is a a `WP object` called `$wp`. How do I access or tranform this into a `WP_Query` object so I can access the passed variables with `get_query_vars()`?

Comment: @Jules: When you `include` a file, it gets executed in the current scope. In this case, it is the `wpse9870_parse_request` function, which only has the `$wp` parameter. It's possible that the global `$wp_query` object hasn't been set at this time, so `get_query_var()` will not work. However, you are lucky: `$wp` is the class that contains the `query_vars` member that you need - I use it myself in the above code.

Comment: @JanFabry Thanks. Figured that out after a while. I was just wondering if there is a way to convert a WP object to a WP_Query object. But I'm not to sure if there would ever even be a need for something like that, so never mind. Thanks for this and all your other pieces of code. Found a lot of helpful information on this site already thanks to you.

Comment: trying to create an external rewrite rules. added your fist piece of code but I am still getting 404. *btw: flushed rewrite rules*

Comment: I'm also still getting a 404 error with external rewrite rules. Just to clarify, the code above goes into the main plugin PHP file, not the templates functions file correct?

Comment: @ethanpil you can (now?) flush the rules to include your new rewrite rules if WP rewrite rules do not include them. The method is documented here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite

Comment: In my case it is work on `index.php?wpse9870_api=1` url and alos `my-api.php?wpse9870_api=1` how i can remove query string?

Comment: @Irfan I am trying to achieve the same can you tell me what I should write in my-api.php ?

Comment: @Prafulla Kumar Sahu I am using like this:
`add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse9870_query_vars' );
        function wpse9870_query_vars( $query_vars )
        {
            $query_vars[] = 'getrequest';
            return $query_vars;
        }
        
        add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse9870_parse_request' );
        function wpse9870_parse_request( &$wp )
        {
            if ( array_key_exists( 'getrequest', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
                include 'my-api.php';
                exit();
            }
            return;
        }`
and url is http://homeurl/?getrequest

Comment: Is the internal rule really stored in the database? Does `add_rewrite_rule`  INSERT into the database? It looks like it is just stored in the source code.

Comment: @ethanpil `flush_rewrite_rules( true );`

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but... where should the `add_action( 'init'...` call go?  I put it in my plugin's `__construct()` method, but the callback method is never executed.  Have tried restarting the server, etc.

Comment: Trying to use the External rule but I'm getting a 403 error when trying to access directly.  The default .htaccess in wp-content is blocking access to the php file in my plugin directory, and none of the .htaccess rules i've added to allow access work.  Any tips?

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me. I never ever touch the rewrite API, but am always up to push myself in new directions. The following worked on my test server for 3.0 located in a sub folder of localhost. I don't for see any issue if WordPress is installed in web root.

Just drop this code in a plugin and upload the file named "taco-kittens.php" directly in the plugin folder. You will need write a hard flush for your permalinks. I think they say the best time to do this is on plugin activation.

```
function taco_kitten_rewrite() {
    $url = str_replace( trailingslashit( site_url() ), '', plugins_url( '/taco-kittens.php', __FILE__ ) );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'taco-kittens\\.php$', $url, 'top' );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'taco_kitten_rewrite' );
```

Best wishes,
-Mike

Comment: I got an access denied error while trying this code. I suspect my server or WP didn't like the absolute URL. This, on the other hand, worked fine: `add_rewrite_rule( 'taco-kittens', 'wp-content/plugins/taco-kittens.php', 'top' );`

Comment: Can you please let me know, what I should put in taco-kittens.php, I do not have knowledge of .htaccess or url rewrite .

Answer (score 11):

Any reason not to do something like this instead?

http://mysite.com/?my-api=1

Then just hook your plugin into 'init' and check for that get variable. If it exists, do what your plugin needs to do and die()

Comment: That would work, but I'm trying to provide a very clear distinction between the query variables and the actual endpoint.  There might be other query args in the future, and I don't want users to mix things up.

Comment: What if you kept the rewrite, but rewrote it to the GET var? You might also look at how the rewrite for robots.txt works. It might help you figure out how to avoid the redirect to my-api.php/

Comment: It is perfect solution if you don't care robots like API calls.

Answer (score 5):

I may not be understanding you questions fully, but would a simple shortcode solve your issue?

Steps:

1. Have the client create a page i.e.
   http://mysite.com/my-api
2. Have the client add a shortcode in that page i.e. [my-api-shortcode]

The new page acts as an API end point and your shortcode sends requests to your plugin code in http://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-api.php

( of course this means that my-api.php would have the shortcode defined )

You can probably automate steps 1 and 2 via the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't dealt with rewrite that much, yet, so this is probably a little rough, but it seems to work:

```
function api_rewrite($wp_rewrite) {
    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules['my-api\.php'] = 'wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-api.php';
    file_put_contents(ABSPATH.'.htaccess', $wp_rewrite->mod_rewrite_rules() );
}
```

It works if you hook this into 'generate_rewrite_rules', but there must be a better way, as you don't want to rewrite .htaccess on each page load.
Seems like i can't stop editing my own posts...it should probably rather go into you activate callback and reference global $wp_rewrite instead. And then remove the entry from non_wp_rules and output to .htaccess again in you deactivate callback.

And finally, the writing to .htaccess should be a bit more sophisticated, you want to only replace the wordpress section in there.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement and wanted to create several end-points based on unique slugs that pointed to content generated by the plugin.

Have a look at the source for my plugin:  https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/picasa-album-uploader/

The technique I used starts by adding a filter for `the_posts` to examine the incoming request.  If the plugin should handle it, a dummy post is generated and an action is added for `template_redirect`.

When the `template_redirect` action is called, it must result in outputting the entire contents of the page to be displayed and exit or it should return with no output generated.  See the code in `wp_include/template-loader.php` and you'll see why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using another approach which consists in **forcing the home page to load a custom title, content and page template**.

The solution is very neat since it can be implemented when a user follows a friendly link such as http://example.com/**?plugin_page=myfakepage**

It is very easy to implement and should allow for unlimited pages.

Code and instructions here: [Generate a custom/fake/virtual Wordpress page on the fly](http://xaviesteve.com/2851/generate-a-custom-fakevirtual-page-on-the-fly-wordpress-plugin-development/)

Answer (score 1):

it's a production readey example , first create virtual page class:

```php
class VirtualPage
{

    private $query;
    private $title;
    private $content;
    private $template;
    private $wp_post;

    function __construct($query = '/index2', $template = 'page', $title = 'Untitled')
    {
        $this->query = filter_var($query, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $this->setTemplate($template);
        $this->setTitle($title);
    }

    function getQuery()
    {
        return $this->query;
    }

    function getTemplate()
    {
        return $this->template;
    }

    function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = filter_var($title, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        return $this;
    }

    function setContent($content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    function setTemplate($template)
    {
        $this->template = $template;

        return $this;
    }

    public function updateWpQuery()
    {

        global $wp, $wp_query;

        // Update the main query
        $wp_query->current_post = $this->wp_post->ID;
        $wp_query->found_posts = 1;
        $wp_query->is_page = true;//important part
        $wp_query->is_singular = true;//important part
        $wp_query->is_single = false;
        $wp_query->is_attachment = false;
        $wp_query->is_archive = false;
        $wp_query->is_category = false;
        $wp_query->is_tag = false;
        $wp_query->is_tax = false;
        $wp_query->is_author = false;
        $wp_query->is_date = false;
        $wp_query->is_year = false;
        $wp_query->is_month = false;
        $wp_query->is_day = false;
        $wp_query->is_time = false;
        $wp_query->is_search = false;
        $wp_query->is_feed = false;
        $wp_query->is_comment_feed = false;
        $wp_query->is_trackback = false;
        $wp_query->is_home = false;
        $wp_query->is_embed = false;
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;
        $wp_query->is_paged = false;
        $wp_query->is_admin = false;
        $wp_query->is_preview = false;
        $wp_query->is_robots = false;
        $wp_query->is_posts_page = false;
        $wp_query->is_post_type_archive = false;
        $wp_query->max_num_pages = 1;
        $wp_query->post = $this->wp_post;
        $wp_query->posts = array($this->wp_post);
        $wp_query->post_count = 1;
        $wp_query->queried_object = $this->wp_post;
        $wp_query->queried_object_id = $this->wp_post->ID;
        $wp_query->query_vars['error'] = '';
        unset($wp_query->query['error']);

        $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $wp_query;

        $wp->query = array();
        $wp->register_globals();

    }

    public function createPage()
    {
        if (is_null($this->wp_post)) {
            $post = new stdClass();
            $post->ID = -99;
            $post->ancestors = array(); // 3.6
            $post->comment_status = 'closed';
            $post->comment_count = 0;
            $post->filter = 'raw';
            $post->guid = home_url($this->query);
            $post->is_virtual = true;
            $post->menu_order = 0;
            $post->pinged = '';
            $post->ping_status = 'closed';
            $post->post_title = $this->title;
            $post->post_name = sanitize_title($this->template); // append random number to avoid clash
            $post->post_content = $this->content ?: '';
            $post->post_excerpt = '';
            $post->post_parent = 0;
            $post->post_type = 'page';
            $post->post_status = 'publish';
            $post->post_date = current_time('mysql');
            $post->post_date_gmt = current_time('mysql', 1);
            $post->modified = $post->post_date;
            $post->modified_gmt = $post->post_date_gmt;
            $post->post_password = '';
            $post->post_content_filtered = '';
            $post->post_author = is_user_logged_in() ? get_current_user_id() : 0;
            $post->post_content = '';
            $post->post_mime_type = '';
            $post->to_ping = '';

            $this->wp_post = new WP_Post($post);
            $this->updateWpQuery();

            @status_header(200);
            wp_cache_add(-99, $this->wp_post, 'posts');

        }


        return $this->wp_post;
    }
}
```

In the next step hook `template_redirect` action and handle your virtual page like below

```php
    add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {


                    switch ( get_query_var( 'name' ,'') ) {

                        case 'contact':
                            // http://yoursite/contact  ==> loads page-contact.php
                            $page = new VirtualPage( "/contact", 'contact',__('Contact Me') );
                            $page->createPage();
                            break;

                        case 'archive':
                            // http://yoursite/archive  ==> loads page-archive.php
                            $page = new VirtualPage( "/archive", 'archive' ,__('Archives'));
                            $page->createPage();
                            break;

                        case 'blog':
                            // http://yoursite/blog  ==> loads page-blog.php
                            $page = new VirtualPage( "/blog", 'blog' ,__('Blog'));
                            $page->createPage();
                            break;


                }


            } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an approach similar to Xavi Esteve's above, which stopped working due to a WordPress upgrade as far as I could tell in the second half of 2013.

It's documented in great detail here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960649/wordpress-plugin-generating-virtual-pages-and-using-theme-template

The key part of my approach is using the existing template so the resulting page looks like it's part of the site; I wanted it to be as compatible as possible with all themes, hopefully across WordPress releases.  Time will tell if I was right!