# How can a plugin create a page/form in the front end?

Tags: plugin-development

How can a plugin create a page/form in the front end thats not listed in pages (if possible). it should only be accessed through a direct link.

Comment: Can you give an example of the URL you want and explain your use case?  If helps us answer if we understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [How do you create a “virtual” page in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress) for the solution. This should work for your case as well.