# Need help with a custom rewrite rule - http://domain/custom post slug/replies

Tags: url-rewriting

I had asked this question in a different way too, but no one replied there! I guess I should rephrase it here.
My custom post is 'company'.
I'm trying to add a custom rewrite rule. When the 'url http://domain..com/company/company-title-slug/replies', is accessed, I want redirect to a custom template(applied to a page named 'replies') with all the comments for this custom post listed. If I add the comment id in the url like this 'url http://domain..com/company/company-title-slug/replies/23', I want to redirect to another page with a custom template applied for displaying a single comment.

This is what I did for accessing the url... 'http://domain.com/replies/reply_id', and it works fine.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^replies/(.*)?$','index.php?pagename=replies&reply_id=$matches[1]','top');
```

Please guide me in the proper direction, having a real hard time with the url rewrite stuff!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but what about:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^company/(.+)/replies/(.*)?$','index.php?pagename=replies&reply_id=$matches[2]','top');
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `add_rewrite_rule` only is not enough. It only adds a new rewrite rule to WP. But you need to register new query variable (in your situation, it's `reply_id`) and parse the request to catch that query variable.

Jan Fabry has posted a [detailed sample](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress/9959#9959) for creating custom rewrite rule, I think it contains all you need.

Comment: Thanks guys. I ended up using a solution similar to  the solution by @devin. Now I can access the url as 'http://domain.com/company/post-slug/replies/comment_id' (exactly how I wanted it). But what I was trying to achieve is, when I access the url 'http://domain.com/replies/comment_id', then the permalink should change to 'http://domain.com/company/post-slug/replies/comment_id'. I guess I need to change the permalink using the post_type_link filter.

Comment: I added the new variable using 'query_vars' filter, and getting it using 'get_query_var'.