# Display custom content using page.php from theme

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am developing a plugin and need to generate a blank page (load the `page.php` from the current theme) and print custom content such as an HTML form or a message.

It should have a URL like `http://example.com/?wpex_page=confirm`

How can I display a page with the current theme's page.php and custom content in it?

**EDIT (18 Jan 2012):**

Found a better and simpler working solution: **[Generate a custom/fake/virtual Wordpress page on the fly](http://xaviesteve.com/2851/generate-a-custom-fakevirtual-page-on-the-fly-wordpress-plugin-development/)**

Comment: I find it a bit hard to undesttand your question, why would a PAGE.PHP clutter the wp_posts?? and second , what do you mean by make the plugin dependable on the WP installation ??

Comment: Sorry, I've removed all that. Question should be clearer now.

Comment: still not sure what you mean by "current theme " but you can always filter the content , or look at the page_template filter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding and catching the query vars (`wpex_page=confirm`) is the simple part [**`as explained in this answer`**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress)  but sine you want to use the theme's default page.php there is something extra you need to do and [**`this is a nice tutorial`**](http://betterwp.net/98-wordpress-create-fake-pages/) which covers it.

Comment: Thanks Bainternet! A 'virtual' page is what I was looking for :)