# Virtual Page with Registration form

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Working on a plugin, which is intended to provide a registration on front-end, to let users register.

I am trying to create a Virtual page, which would display the form.

Trying to create URL like the following http://example.com/plugin_register/register

Have been referring to, [How do you create a 'virtual' page in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress)

But have been unable to make it work with changed query_var, for e.g. if I replace `wpse9870_api` with `plugin_register`, it redirects to home-page or 404 page.

Also referring to [Rewrite API/add rewrite rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

But have been unable to get this work too.

My plugin looks like the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse9870_init_internal' );
function wpse9870_init_internal() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^my-api.php$', 'index.php?wpse9870_api=1', 'top' );
    //add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/?','index.php?wpse9870_api=1','top');
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse9870_query_vars' );
function wpse9870_query_vars( $query_vars ) {
$query_vars[] = 'wpse9870_api';
return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse9870_parse_request' );
function wpse9870_parse_request( &$wp ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'wpse9870_api', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
         include(realpath(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'index.php'));
     //echo plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
     exit();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: make sure you flush the rewrite rules WPAdmin->Settings->Permalink->Save. Sometimes only flushing fix the 404 errors.

Comment: @M-R Thanks mate, you are my sunshine for the day :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you flush the rewrite rules WPAdmin->Settings->Permalink->Save. Sometimes only flushing fix the 404 errors.