# Private Messages between users

Tags: urls, wpdb

I'm RoR programmer but for sometime I play with WordPress. My problem in RoR wouldn't even exist and here I don't know what to do...

I create table

```
wp_wr_messages
```

with all needed fields.

I create for every user page

```
www.domain.com/theme/messages/
```

where I display whole "inbox" for each user_id . But how can I click on some message and get for example new page with content of this message like:

```
/messages/342
```

In other way, how can I create dynamic URL.

Comment: Take a look at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress for how to route virtual urls to your pages.

Comment: wow ... and WordPress want to become a framework? :))))) I spend whole day and I'm not amateur ... this CMS is terrible.

Comment: You may be approaching the development the wrong way. WordPress doesn't want to be a framework. It isn't even trying to be a fully featured CMS. It is first and foremost a blogging platform. If you are approaching the development the same way you would a RoR site, you will absolutely have a hard time. Instead of building this out yourself, you may try looking at what the WP community has already built as plugins - https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/private-message