# Route wordpress with template

Tags: functions, url-rewriting

Some way to create a route in wordpress?

Example:
To create a route (/my-page/) and use a specific template file.

"this to not create a page from WordPress administrator"

the idea is not to use "Create Page"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a "virtual" page in WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-you-create-a-virtual-page-in-wordpress)

Comment: @JacobPeattie is different :(

Comment: How is this different? What do you want to load on this (nonexistant) page?

Comment: If you can be much more specific about what you want to achieve then it will make it easier for people to help.